# Big Lubuntu problem

Tags: lubuntu, mac, boot

I installed Lubuntu 16 using a USB on my PowerMac G4 Quicksilver (alternative installer). The install was fine, after I boot up the Mac and it's fine, I press enter to boot, screen goes white, then goes black, then this?!

[image]

After this happens it goes black again then nothing, ALSO on startup my disc tray opens, yet it is installed just fine?

Is there a fix to this? And why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Help ASAP would be great

Comment: Can you help us with this: Boot your Mac using an Ubuntu Live USB or Live CD, open file manager, navigate to the partition where you have installed the Lubuntu system, go to var/log, then upload the file boot.log here?

Comment: 1. Can't get into Lubuntu. 2. No other computer 3. Only way to upload would be to uninstall Linux and reinstall Mac OS X. This is a tight situation.

Answer (score 0):

hit right shift during boot, press e to edit grub. Add "nomodeset" after the line "quiet splash" with a space before and after. Press F10 to reboot.

Give it a go